# how to solve the loop in IdentityServer4 - connect/authorize/callback?client_id=?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor

hello community I have a project created with asp.net core, blazor webassembly and Identity4, the local project works very well, I published it on an IIS server so that it could be seen from the internet, the project was loaded perfectly, the only detail is that when I enter the login it is loading, until I give it to empty cache and load in a forced way, I can enter the login form, then I enter my credentials and again it stays loading until I empty the cache again and enter the page that indicates I'm already logged in.

> How can I enter the login form without emptying the cache and loading
> forcefully?

When I click the login button, it sends me to this route but it's wrong:

```
connect/authorize?client_id=BlazorApp.Client&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2
```

this is the route that is fine to take me:

```
Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id
```

this is my class startup:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {         

            services.AddDbContext<SimulexContext>
                          (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SimulexConnection")));

           
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
               .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.Configure<PayPalConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("PayPal"));
           

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

           
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            
            services.AddScoped<NotificacionesService>();

            
            services.AddScoped<IAlmacenadorDeArchivos, AlmacenadorArchivosLocal>();
            
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();            
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/api/config/notificacionesllavepublica", async context =>
                 {
                     var configuration = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                     var llavePublica = configuration.GetValue<string>("notificaciones:llave_publica");
                     await context.Response.WriteAsync(llavePublica);
                 });

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();              
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
```

this is my page appsettingsjson:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    },
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorApp.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Did you figured out this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your startup for the blazor app?

I had the same issue a couple weeks ago but with an asp.net mvc app when integrating is4 with which had identity configured. So it could be same for you.

Enet's solution might work, but I have not tried it. Below is another solution which worked for me only if you have Identity configured in your Blazor app. Try setting the schemes in your `services.AddAuthentication` and `AddOpenIdConnect`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Oidc";
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies"; // <-- add this line
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
    {
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies"; // <-- add this line
    })
;
```

Comment: I tried the code that you give me as an example but I get the following error: ArgumentException: Options.ClientId must be provided (Parameter 'ClientId')

Comment: This code was meant for the blazor app, and I removed some code as I assumed you already had, can you update your question to include the blazor app startup.cs code?

Comment: which startup class do you need? already publish my startup class above

Comment: The above startup from blazor or identityserver4?

Comment: I put identity4 to the blazor webassembly project, the identity4 configuration is in the startup class

Comment: Ahh... I recommend to keep both projects separate. have never seen both client and is4 in the same projects. Hence I am not sure how to solve this issue, sorry.